# Welche Präposition gehört zu „Synonym“?

Tags: grammar, preposition

> Ein Synonym zu *good* ist *superb*.

Gehört *zu* zum Wort Synonym?

Ich habe gelesen, dass das Wort *Synonym* mit der Präposition *zu* verwendet werden kann, manchmal mit der Präposition *für*. Welche Präposition ist die richtige?

Comment: Aus dem Bauch heraus: "Ich suche **ein** Synonym **für** X" vs. "**Das** Synonym **zu** X ist Y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer said, both versions are possible and so is *Synonym von*. However, **[Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Synonym%20f%C3%BCr,%20Synonym%20von,%20Synonym%20zu&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Synonym%20f%C3%BCr;,c0;.t1;,Synonym%20von;,c0;.t1;,Synonym%20zu;,c0)** shows that *für* is about 10 times more common.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the correct way of saying that would be

> Das Synonym zu *good* ist *super*.

*Zu* basically means *to*, in this case *belongs to* as a preposition.

> Ich suche ein Synonym zu diesem Wort.
>
> Ich suche ein Synonym für dieses Wort.

There is no difference here. The meaning is the same and both are grammatically correct.